# React Router Param with token having forward slash

Tags: react-router

I am using Identity Framework to generate password reset tokens that have / in the token

e.g.

http://localhost:3000/reset/CfDJ8Gnkh7D2epVEspI7K8JRxtKUjYdzndyduSAhrrg7LjshyYkTwbxzYr3E9CPxBcsPLoocEjplmvaV/Qjug+ez2Kwb0USdwdWMzQm4zJuWiZ1U9+ITrWeUdskiHO9QbdFnfQ/4+ME3TuItAKza0ZrYvi+46f3eiSKVhhe9LhGNWKQRB0KToAMQn7pE1gijIhc5wdPsA+jCCb5ebvDFYIeqo2Yvl/AAuehhpE1mTOWi4alw

How to setup below route path to accept the complete string as token. Below does not seem to work

```
 {
        path: '/reset/:token*',
        element: <ResetSetup />,        
    }

or
 {
        path: '/reset/:token',
        element: <ResetSetup />,        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"/"` character splits path segments, so if a route path parameter value contains this literal character then the entire value won't be captured. The route path can be tweaked a bit to either consume everything after `"/reset/"` as a [splat](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats), e.g. `"/reset/*"`:

```
<Route path="/reset/*" element={<ResetSetup />} />
```

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const ResetSetup = () => {
  const { "*": token } = useParams();

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

This obviously only works if the token value is the final path segment. It won't work if the path was something like `"/reset/<token value>/someOtherSegment"`.

You could encode the token value in a URL-safe way so the *entire* token value is a single path segment, which *would* allow for more dynamic path variations:

```
<Link to={`/reset/${encodeURIComponent("CfDJ8Gnkh7D2epVEspI7K8JRxtKUjYdzndyduSAhrrg7LjshyYkTwbxzYr3E9CPxBcsPLoocEjplmvaV/Qjug+ez2Kwb0USdwdWMzQm4zJuWiZ1U9+ITrWeUdskiHO9QbdFnfQ/4+ME3TuItAKza0ZrYvi+46f3eiSKVhhe9LhGNWKQRB0KToAMQn7pE1gijIhc5wdPsA+jCCb5ebvDFYIeqo2Yvl/AAuehhpE1mTOWi4alw")}`}>
  Reset Password (URI Encoded)
</Link>
```

```
<Route path="/reset/:token" element={<ResetSetup />} />
```

```
const ResetSetup = () => {
  const { token } = useParams();

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

### Demo

[image: Edit react-router-param-with-token-having-forward-slash]

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a + to your Route path ?

```
 {
    path: "/reset/:token+",
    element: <ResetSetup />,        
}
```

Comment: Tried it and that does not work :(
No routes matched location "/reset/CfDJ8Gnkh7D2epVEspI7K8JRxt................

Comment: Okay Other proposal: What about trying "URI-encoding" in the parameter value before joining the full URL path? 
When you create your token, you replace the character '/' by '%2F'. Then, when you receive the result token, you could simply do the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. What I did was encode/decode the URL part that contains slashes. React-router will take the encoded string as a param where you can decoded it later to return the slashes and use as needed

So you can keep:
`path='/reset/:token'`

This will mean what ever takes you to this path will need to encode (`encodeURIComponent`) the `token`. Then when you `useParams` to get the `token` you may need to decode (`decodeURIComponent`) the `token`. I say may because I believe react-router will decode it in-flight